# ROS Answers SE migration: Segway Driver

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to install the Segwayrmp driver and get it to work properly. But now it is showing a 'checksum mismatch' error.
Any solution to this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172597/segway-driver/) by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2014-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I remember correctly this occurs when there is invalid data sent from the segway device and typically this means some sort of problem with the usb device. I remember debugging this once and finding lots of messages about usb failures in `dmesg`. If you are using USB to connect to the segway, try passing it through a powered USB hub or rethinking your power system to try and identify places where your could have different grounds.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2014-06-02**:
Additionally. If the checksum mismtach error only shows once, don't worry about it. That's typical. If it shows up more than once, then you probably have a problem.